# It is appropriate to ask for in-game tips and tricks

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, questions

It is appropriate to ask for in-game tips and tricks as long as I narrow down to a certain play-style, etc?
For example :
I ask for tips/tricks for improvement in Battlefield, stating that I like to play aggressive and with a rifle, etc.

It is appropriate to ask those kind of question(s)?
If yes, is there anything I should definitely take note of when asking those types of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already have over 400 questions that contain the word advice (and most of them are actual advice requests), so asking for tips and tricks is definitely on-topic.

However, we need to have a problem statement. A simple "tips and tricks for playing aggressive rifle user in Battlefield" would probably end up too broad. Instead, you need to have something you're struggling with as a rifle user, or a number of somethings, and mention those in your question.